# RedBeanPHP - нет соединения с БД

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

Оба сайта на одном лок. хостинге - на одном `RedBeanPHP` соед. с БД, а на другом - нет - выдает ошибку:   http://joxi.ru/v294gWxf3ngZpm.jpg
В чем, кроме путей, может быть причина??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как ни странно, в сообщении об ошибке про БД не сказано ровным счетом ничего. Оно у вас гласит

> Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare class `ReadBeanPHP\RedException`

Что в переводе на русский обозначениет, что пхп не может повторно определить класс `RedException`, поскольку он уже был определен ранее.

Из стека видно, что используются конструкции `include` и `require`, из чего следует, что файл, в котором определен данный класс исключений, подключается как минимум два раза.

Дабы избежать подобной сиутации, используйте `include_once` и `require_once`.